# Redis-server - FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR - Filepath Space problem

Tags: redis

I am trying to start the redis-server that was installed in windows PC as deamonize service.

I configured the redis.conf file to accept the pidfile and logfile path as follows:

```
pidfile D:\HMS Build\redis\bin\redis.pid
....
logfile D:\HMS Build\logs\redis.log
```

While i was trying to start the server, i am getting the following error message.

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 52
>>> 'logfile D:\HMS Build\logs\redis.log'
Can't open the log file: Invalid argument
```

I would like to know how to provide the filepath that has spaces in it.

I tried with single quote, double quote, but the result is the same: Error

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: add double quotes and replace \ by / (yes, on Windows)

```
logfile "D:/HMS Build/logs/redis.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the file name with quotes, as you have a space in your folder name. It is something that always gets me. Try this:

```
logfile "D:\HMS Build\logs\redis.log"
```

Comment: I tried with quotes(single & double), It is still showing the error. Right now i solved the problem with relative path (i.e) something like this: ../logs/redis.log

Answer (score 0):

logfile default is set to "", and you will need to include quotes

```
logfile "D:/HMS Build/logs/redis.log"
```

then, you need to start Redis by running,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start
```

if you are following the installation steps from http://redis.io/topics/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

change the backslash to slash.

in my case :

> logfile "D:/Database/redis/server.log"

The relative path can not be used on other drive.

Comment: Yes, on Windows 8.1 & Redis-x64-2.8.2400. (The relative path works on same drive.)